# Prevent default anchor behaviour if checkbox inside clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular ui-bootstrap for accordion and for panel-heading I also need **checkbox**, which is generated inside anchor tag by ui-bootstrap. It looks like this (checkbox is inside `<label>` 'cause of styling):

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading">
   <span>Some headline</span>
   <label class="checkbox-toggle-btn">
      <span>Activate</span>
      <input data-ng-model="selected[service.name]" type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected[service.name]">
      <i></i>
   </label>
</a>
```

By clicking on checkbox (`<label>`) it doesn't behave as checkbox but `<a>` is clicked and accordion expanded.

How can I preventDefault `<a>` tag behaviour if is clicked inside `<label>`?
Can I use directive on label and access the parent element?

Comment: did you try `e.stopPropagation();` on `<a>` tag click?

Comment: I've tried, no effect.

Comment: actually the `e.stopPropagation();` should be on the label click, so to prevent any parent calls, adding it on the <a> tag would only stop <a>'s parent calls

Comment: Stop producing invalid HTML to begin with – `label` is considered “interactive content”, and as such it is not allowed as descendant of an `a` element. (And for `input` it’s the same, of course.)

Comment: @CBroe - You're right, but I'm doing it like that 'cause of ui-bootstrap's accordion structure. Maybe it should be done in different way, don't know it in this moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```
<label ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"></label>
```

Comment: I believe that should be inside of the the `ng-checked` directive, not the `ng-click` on the anchor tag. Or maybe you need to add an `ng-click` to the label and perform that operation.

Comment: Maybe
<label ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">

Comment: Yes, that's working solution, stopPropagation() on label tag, thank you.

Comment: @swolfish, you can accept a correct answer once the best solution is provided for you. thank you.

Comment: @Noypi - Yes, I know, but waiting for edit accepted, to be fully correct. ;)